# How to use assign syntax when processing bash arguments in a loop?

Tags: linux, bash

I have the following loop to read and set variables passed to a bash script

```
while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do

        if [[ $1 == *"--"* ]]; then
                param="${1/--/}"
                declare $param="$2"
                # echo $1 $2 // Optional to see the parameter:value result
        fi

        shift
done
```

For example one can call it via:

```
sh test.sh --name myname --family myfamily
```

How can I change it to call it as:

```
sh test.sh --name=myname --family=myfamily
```

Comment: Why? just use `getopts` or `getopt`

Comment: @Inian you mean `getopts` support `=` between option-value? However, I found above code or the modifcation in accepted answer an easy solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use variable content substitution syntax in bash to "arrange" one argument in several substring. The first substring is **--** (that you're already removing) the second substring will be the variable name, the third will be **=** and the last will be the variable content.

This can be done by a slight modification to your script:

```
while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do

        if [[ $1 == *"--"* ]]; then
                param="${1/--/}"
                value="${param##*=}"
                param="${param%%=*}"
                declare $param="$value"
                echo variable name: $param 
                eval echo variable content: '$'"$param"
        fi

        shift
done
```

This way, if I feed these parameters to the new script:

```
sh test.sh --name=myname --family=myfamily
```

I get the following output:

```
variable name: name
variable content: myname
variable name: family
variable content: myfamily
```